# Trying to figure out difference in sorting

Tags: java, excel, sorting, selenium

I have to verify a column in a table is sorted correctly. I take the column, put into a Java list and do a `Collections.sort()` ignoring case.  The Java sort is different from the sort in the column of the table.  I noticed the table is sorting the same way as Microsoft Excel is sorting.  I am trying to find the difference so I can do the Java sort correctly (maybe Local).

My system properties in Windows shows `en.us`.  Anyway I sorted the characters both ways and am showing you below.  The first, standard Latin, is the Java sort.  The second, I am not sure exactly what type it is, is the table sort and Excel sort.  Can anyone figure out how I can make the Java sort match it (one difference is it uses ignore case which I also need to).

== **Collections.sort()**

```
#   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   -   .   /   0   1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   :   ;   <   =   >   ?   @   A   B   C   D   E   F   G
H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y
Z   [   \   ]   ^   _   `   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   
l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z   {   |   }
```

== **Excel/table sort**

```
'   -   #   $   %   &   (   )   *   ,   .   /   :   ;   ?   @   [   \   ]   
^   _   `   {   |   }   +   <   =   >   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   
9   A   a   B   b   C   c   D   d   E   e   F   f   G   g   H   h   I   i   
J   j   K   k   L   l   M   m   N   n   O   o   P   p   Q   q   R   r   S   
s   T   t   U   u   V   v   W   w   X   x   Y   y   Z   z
```

Comment: Note: It is more than just the upper/lower case characters which are sorting differently.  When I use ignore case it sorts the letters as the other, but other characters are not.

Comment: It has to do with the character encoding. Excel I'm pretty sure uses ANSI or some other encoding. The first group is sorted by UTF-8 character code value of each character.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-ca/article/About-sorting-bfea8d83-145b-400f-9ecf-8f7189945185

> Data analysis begins with sorting. You can sort text (A to Z or Z to A), numbers (smallest to largest or largest to smallest), and dates and times (oldest to newest and newest to oldest) in one or more columns. You can also sort by a custom list that you create (such as Large, Medium, and Small). Or you can sort by format, including cell color, font color, or icon set. Most frequently, you will sort by column, but you can also sort by rows.
>
> When you sort, you rearrange data into some order. In contrast, when you filter, you hide extraneous data. For more information about filtering, see About filtering.
>
> When you sort on a range of cells, the sort criteria aren't saved with your workbook. If you want to save sort criteria so that you can reapply it the next time that you open the workbook, you can save the data as a Excel table. Save your data in a table when you are sorting multiple columns or if you create complex sorting criteria that takes a long time to create.
>
> When you reapply a sorting criteria, you may see different results. This can occur if values that are returned by a formula have changed and the sheet is recalculated. It can also occur if the range of cells or table column has had data added, changed, or deleted.
>
> Excel sorts data by using the following ascending sort order:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 (space) ! " # $ % & ( ) * , . / : ; ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~ + < = > a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z FALSE TRUE (sheet errors) (blank cells).

So the sort order will not be the same as Collections.sort(). Since Java is more than likely sorting the characters according to UTF-8.

Not sure which encoding Excel is using but you can change the behaviour of Collections.sort() as follows:

```
Collator collector = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);
collector.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
Collections.sort(list, collector);
```

There is lots of documentation on this in the javadocs.

Comment: I tried that but it did not work.  It sorted the same Java way.  I did write a comparator I think might work.  What do you think of this?